# shiro authentication against remote server given the logintoken

Tags: nexus, shiro

I have a nexus oss instance running on my laptop. What I want to do is , I will send a userlogintoken in a request sent to this nexus oss and get the userlogintoken from the nexus oss plugin and then authenticate it against teamforge(my application name) which runs in a different box.

In nexus oss they use shiro . So I too will use shiro in my nexus plugin that will do authentication against teamforge . I don't know where to start . Can I have some examples that can run standalone , which can do the task as mentioned above , so that I can start moving from there.

so requirement is basically that I need to give the server url and the userlogintoken to shiro  and  have to authenticate against the server url provided using that logintoken provided.

I refered a number of places searching for this kind of shiro example as I am extremely new to shiro , but I did not find examples that can do authentication given a remote server url (in my case the teamforge url).there are examples for authentication from usernames , passwords stored in ini files , or in database , but did not find examples for my use case .

Can somebody please guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement your own `org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm` you can make it configurable via `Shiro.ini` quite easily. You have to create public getter/setter with same name as property in ini file.

You need to implement `protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)` and `protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)` methods. They are called during `currentUser.login(token)`.

**Shiro.ini**

```
customRealm= me.harish.shiro.realm.CustomRealm
customRealm.url = http://teamforge.com/?loginme
customRealm.apiKey = ABCD
customRealm.apiSecret = magic1

securityManager.realms= $customRealm
```

Some helpful links:

https://www.google.sk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#fp=5cd33cfa2e98ac64&q=custom%20realm%20shiro

http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html